# Install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
tim@tim-virtual-machine:~/rails_projects/first_app$ bundle install
ERROR: RVM Ruby not used, run `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial` first.
tim@tim-virtual-machine:~/rails_projects/first_app$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I'm currently using ruby-1.9.3-p448, but why the command 'bundle install' prompt "ERROR: RVM Ruby not used"?

Comment: Did you create `rvm` config files (e.g., `.ruby-gemset` or `.ruby-version`) in your project folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure RVM is correctly installed and that your .bash_profile file has the correct line:

```
[[ -s "/home/tim/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/home/tim/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command when you use rvm  :

> rvm use ruby 1.9

and then run bundler again.

let me know error has removed.